# Programmatically setting derby.system.home

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Need to move the database and log files of JavaDB (derby) db files into deployment directories.  The database is working in the application startup directory as JavaDB creates a folder with the name of the database (in my case mydb), but I want to move that dir into a subdir called data/ creating data/mydb.  I can do this with the connect call:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:data/mydb;create=false");
```

and this works.  But I'd like to programmatically explicitly set the value of

derby.system.home=data/
derby.stream.error.file=log/derby.log

So I can do:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:mydb;create=false");
```

and all dbs would be in that data/ dir.  And the derby log file would be in logs/!  I just can't seem to figure this out.  Anyone help?  Is there a way to set those properties programatically (because it's embedded)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation (Derby developers guide: Setting Derby properties)](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevsetprop11561.html) suggests something like:

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.setProperty("derby.system.home", "C:\databases\sample");
```

I've also seen

```
/* setting an attribute in a Properties object */
Properties myProps = new Properties();
myProps.put("create", "true");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:sampleDB", myProps);
```

Comment: This works for database properties and I actually use something close to this in my code.  But this does not work for System-Wide properties.

Comment: The link in the answer contains the above code under section *Setting Derby properties* -> *Changing System-wide properties programmatically*. So the error is perhaps elsewhere in your code. (You could also try the other approach, "Changing the system-wide properties by using the derby.properties file".

Comment: Nope you're correct!  The first part got me going down the correct path. Duh its a darn system property. So I added: System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "./data/"); and System.setProperty("derby.stream.error.file", "../log/derby.log"); (<- this was because the root dir is now data/) and it all works great!  Yeah I don't want to use a derby.properties file.

Comment: @aioobe link is broken