# jar file connection with Database

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am working on a JAVA Database Project. My database is derby database present in IDE Netbeans. I had made a jar file of my project. Database works only when IDE is in a running condition. When I run IDE and opens jar file, it's correctly fetches the data from the database. But, when I close IDE and then run jar file, the jar file runs but it doesn't connect to the database because of the terminated IDE. I want the jar file works same in both conditions i.e; running and terminated IDE. Any suggestions or solutions ? I have also cleaned and build my project many times but all in vain.

Comment: there may be a fault in jars or class path, Try running the Jar from the command line for more information, using something like java -jar the.jar

Comment: run your jar on command line: [java -jar yourJarFile.jar] and tell about what you see as exception.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085778/how-to-run-database-program-outside-the-netbeans-ide